# Storing mixed data types in Swift .plist file

Tags: ios, swift, list, file, properties

My apps stores its data of mixed data types - `integers, text, images, and sound files`.  The images can be up to `1.2 MB`.

I can store all the data in one `.plist file`, or I can store the images and audio as individual files outside of the .plist file.

Serializing all the data in one .plist file sounds like the best (cleanest) approach, but is it?

Comment: why don't you use core data or NSUserDefaults instead using `.plist`

Comment: [NSUserDefaults is not a database](http://b2cloud.com.au/general-thoughts/nsuserdefaults-is-not-a-database/) - the best bet is probably CoreData or sqlite.

Comment: I'm concerned about storing images in core data or SQLite - in the past I've read that storing images in core data isn't a good idea at least, but I'm not sure if that is still the case.